# Does Stack Exchange Track Clicks to "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, hot-questions, data-analysis

I'd love to make or see a graph analysis of click-throughs from Stack Overflow to other community's questions. I expect to see attractors that SO types tend to fall into (e.g. RPGs).

Does Stack Exchange have a mechanism for recording these clicks? Is this data available anywhere?

Comment: @Stilly.stack there is a referrer header sent from the browser which also tells where the user is coming from so the team can analyse this if they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be partially tracked, but I do not think we have access to this data.

The Hot Network Questions link URLs don't currently include a tracking parameter. However, there is the HTTP `Referer` header which can track this for the most part. There are some limitations on using the `Referer` header only:

- If a hot question is visited from a **different site**, during the period it was on Hot Network Questions, then they can be reasonably sure that it accessed was via the Hot Network Questions list.
- You know it was not via the **Featured Question Ads** because those *do* have a tracking parameter.
- Unfortunately, Stack Exchange could not readily distinguish a **user link** to a different site, vs a Hot Network Questions link.

  For example, if you click this here: [How does an attacker get access to hashed passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134679/how-does-an-attacker-get-access-to-hashed-passwords?s=8%7C1.3455)
  Stack Exchange cannot tell whether it was from the link I just gave you, or the Hot Network Questions on the right column.
- If you are viewing [Stack Exchange in `https` mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231283/does-stack-exchange-track-clicks-to-hot-network-questions), then, because the Hot Network Questions are still `http` links (they should fix this one day), the `Referer` would be stripped during navigation from an `https` to `http` connection.
- **Same-site** tracking just doesn't work. User links in the same site are much more common *and* I can find the same question either by search, or in this case, on the home page:

[image: Hot Network Question is also on the Home Page]

So in summary, they just can't track this for same-site navigation. With cross-site navigation they can track these with reasonable accuracy, but not 100%.

I wonder why they have not added a tracking identifier to the URL? You would think it would be useful data for them to have, even if just for internal purposes. :-)