# Where can I see at what time a hot network question lost its "hot network question" status?

Tags: support, hot-questions, timeline

The question timeline indicates when a question becomes a hot network question but doesn't seem to indicate when  it loses  its "hot network question" status, unless a moderator manually removed it from the hot network questions.

Where can I see at what time a hot network question lost its "hot network question" status?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way. As the announcement [Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less "hotness"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt) says, *right now we don't have an event for a post dropping off the list. The concern with this is that questions right on the edge of the list may pop on and off the list several times, as frequently as every fifteen minutes, thus cluttering up the history*.

Comment: related: [Add an audit log to record when particular question enters and leaves hot list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238445/165773). BTW I dropped the "leaving" part of my old feature request after I realised that it is much more complicated compared to recording first entry into the list: voting up and down can cause question leave and re-enter hot list many times...

Comment: ...and if you add that there are also other questions at play, with their own voting dynamics and aging factors it becomes even harder, at this point I just thought it's not worth it since system guarantees that after 3 days question will leave hot list no matter what

Comment: Franck, interesting additional information: Going on and coming off is [determined by this formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/282094) (still currently used), which is recalculated every 15 minutes; though it doesn't calculate entry and exit times.

Comment: @Rob et al. very relevant and interesting links, thanks!